# How to do t.test (two samples) to rows of a dataframe using apply family function?

Tags: r

How to do t.test  to rows (with two levels, or in other words, groups of samples) of a dataframe using apply family function? I have done that using function and loops. And my overall purpose is to calculate DE genes from two groups of miRNA microarray samples. And I know limma can do that, but it seems limma doesn't support paired t-test.

```
t.test.df=function(df,paired){
  df.t=c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df.t=rbind(df.t,unlist(t.test(df[i,grp1],df[i,grp2],paired=paired)))
  }
  rownames(df.t)=rownames(df)
  df.t
}
```

Bests!
Allen Chiu

Comment: if you provide an example of `df` I'm sure it will make it easier for folks to provide you with some useful guidance.

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't give an example of your data here is some sample data in a data.frame called counts. In this example there are 3 cases and 3 controls

```
Gene   S1      S2      S3      S4      S5      S6
1   20000   12032   23948    2794    5870     782
3   15051   17543   18590   21005   22996   26448
4   35023   43092   41858   39637   40933   38865

t.result <- apply(counts[,2:7], 1, function (x) t.test(x[1:3],x[4:6],paired=TRUE))

counts$p_value <- unlist(lapply(t.result, function(x) x$p.value))
```

You will also need some sort of multiple testing correction.

```
counts$fdr <- p.adjust(counts$p_value, method = "fdr")
```

use `?p.adjust` to see other methods

Comment: God job! Can you tell me how to do multiple testing correction please?